# Using Azure Blob storage to save raster and vector data and use it with GeoServer

Tags: raster, geoserver, vector, azure

My client has large datasets store in Azure Blob storage. Is there any way to use them directly via Azure Blob storage? I had a look at *Azure GWC plugin* but it is just allowing me to cache the existing raster image in blob storage.

Comment: there is an unsupported S3-GeoTiff module that might provide a starting point if you want to implement something for them

Comment: Cool, thanks mate! I’ll check it out,do u also know anything for vector data 